# add time when we save a Timefield in django

Tags: python, django

I have a `dateTime` field in a model. The dateTime field named `breakfast_start_time` takes an input.
I have to save another variable or timefield(whichever is better) named `breakfast_attendence_start_time` whose value should be automatically saved 15 minutes less than the `breakfast_start_time`.
For this we use

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #do something
    super().save(*args, *kwargs)
```

I am trying to do

```
breakfast_attendence_start_time = breakfast_start_time - time(15,0)
```

but it is giving error that

```
class TimeField does not define '_sub_', so the '-' operator cannot be used on its instances
```

Edited:

Here is the full code

```
class Hostel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    breakfast_start_time = models.TimeField()
    lunch_start_time = models.TimeField()
    snacks_start_time = models.TimeField()
    dinner_start_time = models.TimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am taking start time from admin panel and I want to add 4 more variable/field like `breakfast_attendence_start_time` whose value should be saved automatically 15 minutes earlier than `breakfast_start_time` how can I achive that.

Comment: Please show the full code - in context - and the traceback. Exactly what are `breakfast_attendence_start_time` and `breakfast_start_time` here? They shouldn't be *field* instances.

Comment: meal_start_time is an instance of `models.TimeField`

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. **Where** is this code? It shouldn't be an instance of the field, it should be an instance of the *value* stored by that field, eg Time. Show the **full** code, in context.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `timedelta` to sub specific time with `DateTime` field. Such as

```py
import datetime

time_before_15_minute = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTimeField instead of TimeField and use timedelta to make substractions

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
n = datetime(2019, 10, 4, 12, 30)
m = n - timedelta(minutes = 15) # m is now datetime(2019, 10, 4, 12, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the DateTimeField but this will return time of when this function was called or used. Hope it helps

```
from django.utils import timezone
class AKA(models.Model):
create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
def __str__(self):
        return self.create_time
```